# Creating tag synonyms for a new tag

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Yesterday a new tag [position](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/position) was created. There are lots of position-related problems on the site, but all of them just used `list-manipulation`. So I think such tag is not necessary. However, when I try to create a tag synonym, it says I need 5 score on this tag to do so. Is this promoting that we should use the tag  in order to get it merged?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this promoting that we should use the tag in order to get it merged?

No, the synonym is the inferior object so if you propose a synonym for [position](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/position) then you claim the proposed one should be replaced by [position](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/position) in future. This is not the case here.

You should go to the tag you think is already covering that area and propose a synonym for [position](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/position) in this case.

---

New users create many new, redundant/too specific, tags and our task is to retag those questions if that is the case. Informing OP to not create tags in future unless they seem essential.

further reading:

[What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/233085)

Comment: Thanks! I thought it was the opposite.

Comment: Would [tag:searching] perhaps be a better master tag for "position"?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard hard to argue without wiki. But since you mention it I'd make [tag:searching] a synonym for [tag:filtering] too. The latter has a good wiki and more tagged topics. Unless I'm missing a specific area where we need searching and filtering does not apply.